# Transaction is not getting rolled back with 2 instances of Transaction and nested methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, rollback

I need to insert records in multiple tables, but these tables are belonging to different schemas so transaction values are also different. But I want to insert records in all the tables atomically ( all or nothing). Following code I have tried to handle this.

```
@Transactional(value = "First")
public void insert(String f1, String f2, String f3, String f4){
    try {
        Entity1 entity1 = createEntity1(f1);
        FirstTable1.insert(entity1);
        insertInSecondSchema(f2, f3, f4);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        String errorMessage = "Error occur while inserting in first schema";
        logger.error(errorMessage, e);
        throw new CustomException(errorMessage,e);
    }
}

@Transactional(value = "second")
private void insertInSecondSchema(String f2, String f3, String f4) {
    try {
        Entity2 entity2 = createEntity2(f2);
        SecondTable2.insert(entity2);

        Entity3 entity3 = createEntity3(f3);
        SecondTable3.insert(entity3);

        Entity4 entity4 = createEntity4(f4);
        SecondTable4.insert(entity4);

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            String errorMessage = "Error occur while inserting in second schema";
            logger.error(errorMessage, e);
            throw new CustomException(errorMessage,e);
    }
}
```

In this scenario if some error occurs while inserting in SecondTable3. SecondTable2 is not rolled back but FirstTable1 is rolled-back. I have tried many propagation level in secondMethod, but none of them working for me. Please help how can I fix this using same code or some other code structure.

Comment: `@Transactional` on a `private` method won't work. `@Transactional` is implemented using AOP, AOP in spring is proxy based. Proxy based AOP will only work for methods calls going into the object not for internal method calls. So basically you only have 1 transaction here as the second `@Transactional` is totally ignored.

Comment: Please read my comment. Making it public won't help because it still is an internal method call.

Comment: Okay I understood now why it is not working, what could be the way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation I think is better to think as if this was a distributed system. In this case, you cannot make these insertions transactional, instead of that, you should use compensating actions in case one of the transaction succeeds and the other fails.

In your case if insertInSecondSchema fails then you have to call delete of the same record for the first schema, so the result is like the first insertion never happens